# Why is build_runner is succeeding with 0 outputs?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, mockito, build-runner

I have a simple Dart class that is using the package Dio in one of its methods. In the class's corresponding test file, I'm trying to mock Dio by placing `@GenerateMocks([Dio])` above the main method. I then ran `dart run build_runner build` to generate the mocks for Dio. But no mocks were generated. The command line outputted the following:

```
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 143ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 53ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 628ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 3ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 41ms
[INFO] Succeeded after 48ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)
```

Why is it not generating anything?

I tried updating my dependencies thinking that maybe this was the issue but it wasn't.

```
test: ^1.24.9
mockito: ^5.4.4
build_runner: ^2.4.8
```

I've run `dart run build_runner build` from the root of the project, and I get 0 outputs. I've also run it from the folder where the test is located and that errored out.

I've also tried generating mocks for a different class, but that had the exact same result.

Any ideas for what build_runner isn't generating anything?

Comment: Have you added `part filename.g.dart`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I haven't seen that. What is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. It was because I had my tests in the `tests/` directory instead of the `test/` directory (no "s"). The code generator won't find the tests if they aren't in the test/ directory. ‍♂️ Once I put them in the correct dir, the code generator generated the mocks properly.

Answer (score 0):

In every file that has some code that needs to be generated, you have to include
`part 'the_file_name.g.dart';` after the imports section. For example, if the file name is `foo.dart`, then you have to add this:

```dart
part 'foo.g.dart';
```

This will tell build_runner to generate the missing part file.

Comment: Then why does the mockito documentation not have this anywhere? All that the mockito docs say to do is place the @GenerateMocks([]) above the main() function in your test file. They don't mention adding the `part`.

Comment: See my answer below. Once I put the tests in he proper directory, I actually didn't have to put `part [].g.dart` in my files. It worked just with the @GenerateMocks([]) annotation.

Comment: You were right, I checked the mockito documentation and it does not need the `part` line. It's usually needed in other code-generation packages, though